# Vertical-align works strangely (on cell-tabs)

Tags: html, css, inline, vertical-alignment

I have a problem using the vertical-align:top; property on a cell-tab css content.

Here the picture : http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/157625Capture.png

My HTML code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style_test.css" />
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div class='tableau'>
            AAAA<img class='img1' src='images/drapeau_anglais.gif' />
            <img class='img2' src='images/drapeau_anglais.gif' />
            <span>BBBB</span> 
            <!-- This text lose the vertical-align:top; propertie because it is in the <span> => WHY ??? -->
            <p>CCCC<img src='images/drapeau_anglais.gif' />DDDD</p>
            <!-- As in the span, everything in my <p> loose it s vertical align propertie -->
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My CSS code :

```
    .tableau
{
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid black;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.tableau p
{
    display:inline-block;
}
.img1
{
    /* I dont say anything here. img1 SHOULD be on top because of the ".tableau" class but it doesnt... why???*/
}
.img2
{
    /* I force the vertical align on my image (but I shouldnt have to do that normally ?) But with this "trick" it works */
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I commend you for wanting to understand. The problem with `vertical-align` is that it doesn't take much HTML and CSS for there to be quite a lot going on. What we can do it to build the layout up piece by piece.

### **AAAA**

This text is placed in a anonymous inline box. This goes in a line box, preceded by a zero-width inline box that's the height of the container element's font, called the strut. The strut and the AAAA text are vertically aligned with each other with respect to each others baseline. So already, we have

[image: Figure with AAAA text, strut, baseline and line box]

### **`<img class='img1' src='...' />`**

The vertical-align of the .img1 element is the default which is baseline, and images are replaced inline elements, so the baseline of the image is its bottom margin edge. .img1 has no margins, border or padding, so that makes it the bottom edge of the image itself, so now, if we assume that the image is taller than the font, we have

[image: addition of img element to the first figure]

Note that the line box is now taller than previously to accommodate the image. In fact the line box is taller than any of its component parts.

### **`<img class='img2' src='...' />` part one**

We'll skip the second image for the moment and come back to it later. We'll just leave a placeholder for now.

### **`<span>BBBB</span>`**

Exactly as AAAA, except that here the inline box is formed from a real element rather than being anonymous. This gives us

[image: addition of placeholder and BBBB text to figure 2]

### **CCCC`<img src='...' />`DDDD**

This is exactly like `AAAA<img src='...' />`BBBB`. Nothing new to add here.

### **`<p>CC...DD</p>`**

The p element is set to inline-block, which means that its line-height contribution to the line it is in is its margin box. It has default margins from the user agent stylesheet of (typically) 1em top and bottom. It too is aligned to the other elements on the line using its baseline. So now we have

[image: addition of p element to figure 3]

Again the line box grows in height, this time to accommodate the p element's margin box.

### **`<img class='img2' src='...' />` part two**

Now we can fill in the placeholder we left earlier for .img2. This image is `vertical align:top`, so it doesn't align with the other elements, but with the top of the line box. So that gives us

[image: addition of top aligned image to figure 4]

### **`.tableau { display:table-cell; vertical-align:top; }`**

Then the **whole thing** is wrapped up as one and positioned at the top of the table-cell.

### **Wrap up**

Finally, we need to account for why "AAAA" appears at the top in your picture and not aligned to the other text as depicted in my answer above. This seems to be because you captured the picture from Chrome, and was therefore subjected to Chrome's screwy vertical-align implementation. Firefox and IE display the layout correctly.

Answer (score 0):

With your `vertial-align: top` You mean about effect like here: http://jsfiddle.net/bdoq99a2/1/

I've simply changed this:

```
.tableau *{
   display: inline;
}
```

Image: http://take.ms/BxlzD

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the browser stylesheet, in this case the default margin for paragraphs. No need to fuss around with display: table-cell and vertical-align: top. Just check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bdoq99a2/2/

```css
.tableau {
    border:1px solid black;
}
.tableau p {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='tableau'>
  AAAA<img class='img1' src='http://lorempixel.com/400/200/' />
  <img class='img3' src='http://lorempixel.com/300/200/' />
  <span>BBBB</span> 
  <p>CCCC<img src='http://lorempixel.com/300/200/' />DDDD</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it explains why the images aren't on the top but it doesn't explain why the text in my span tag doesn't respect my vertical align.
Could you help me for this ?

In fact I need a table cell because i use it with other cells which are not represented here.

Comment: Just add 
`.tableau img {
    vertical-align: text-top;
}`

Comment: Thanks, it works but I dont understand why and I would like to

Should'nt my property "vertical-align:top;" on my table cell force all the content in it to be on top ? (excepted for margin with the example of the p that your corrected).

I dont understand why the span doesn't respect this rule ?

Comment: It IS aligned to the top then, but there is also an alignment of inline elements relative to each other. That's why the images are on top then, but the text on bottom, because I believe the default rendering of the elements to each other is vertical-align: text-bottom.

Comment: Hmmm i'm not sure to understand it very well.

You say that the default rendering says that the span (for example) has in it's properties "vertical-align:text-bottom;".

But this default property should be "replaced" by mine ? I mean that the vertical-align:top; that i put on my table-cell should replace the default browser rendering ?

Sorry for this but I really want to understand css well now because in the past i lost a lot of time by trying "tricks" instead of understanding well what I did.

Comment: No, my statement referred to how images render in relation to adjacent inline text.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand.
Could you re explain the whole thing ?
You say that images must be rendered with next elements with a vertical-align:text-bottom; But i dont see how it could be vertical-align:top; because of the cell WITH the condition vertical-align:bottom-text; on the image.
The vertical-align:top; of my cell is just applied on "pure text" but not on extra tags that are in the cell ?

Comment: Applying `vertical-align: top;` on the table-cell makes sure elements are rendered in visual top-down-order related to the cell. Then there is content within that cell, a series of inline elements. Inline = "in line" - this "line" sticks to the top of the cell because of the table-cell's `vertical-align: top;`. But on top of that there is an alignment within that "line". Since in this case the images are higher than your text, the browser has to decide how to align the elements in line. In this line the images have a default of aligning with the text baseline.